# Why don't static member variables play well with the ternary operator?

Tags: c++, static, ternary-operator, static-members

Here's the deal. I have a static class which contains several static functions used for getting input. The class contains a private static member variable for indicating whether the user entered any information. Each input method checks to see whether the user entered any information, and sets the status variable accordingly. I think this would be a good time to use the ternary operator. Unfortunately, I can't, because the compiler doesn't like that.

I replicated the problem, then simplified my code as much as was possible to make it easy to understand. This is not my original code.

Here's my header file:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    void go ();
private:
    static const int GOOD = 0;
    static const int BAD = 1;
};
```

Here's my implementation with the ternary operator:

```
#include "test.h"

void Test::go () {
    int num = 3;
    int localStatus;
    localStatus = (num > 2) ? GOOD : BAD;
}
```

Here's main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {
    Test test = Test();
    test.go();
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get this error message:

```
test.o: In function `Test::go()':
test.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `Test::GOOD'
test.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `Test::BAD'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, if I replace this:

```
localStatus = (num > 2) ? GOOD : BAD;
```

with this:

```
if (num > 2) {
    localStatus = GOOD;
} else {
    localStatus = BAD;
}
```

The code compiles and runs as expected. What obscure C++ rule or GCC corner case is responsible for this lunacy? (I'm using GCC 4.4.1 on Ubuntu 9.10.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is according to the C++ Standard. The ternary operator does constitute a single lvalue that will refer to either `GOOD` or `BAD` at runtime. The lvalue to rvalue conversion is not applied immediately to either the lvalue `GOOD` or `BAD`, and therefor you require a definition of `GOOD` and `BAD`.

See the core language issue report http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#712 .

As a workaround, you can apply explicit casts to `int` (which reads their values, thereby doing an lvalue to rvalue conversion) or use an operator that reads the value, like `+`:

```
localStatus = (num > 2) ? +GOOD : +BAD;
```

Comment: Where does the standard distinguish between the two cases? Don't they both "use" `GOOD`, and therefore require a definition? I think it's just that gcc is smart enough to avoid the external link in the case of lvalue `GOOD` being used as the RHS of an assignment (and hence is immediately lvaue-rvalue converted), but hasn't managed it in the case of lvalue `GOOD` used in a ternary operator, but I'm prepared to believe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Steve if you do `+GOOD` or `int a = GOOD`, you do the lvalue to rvalue conversion on the lvalue `GOOD` ("directly" - see 3.2p2, which says in such cases you don't "use" the variable). If you do `int a = x ? a : b;`, you would do the lvalue to rvalue conversion on the lvalue that the ternary operator yields, not on the lvalue that `a` and `b` yield.

Comment: Ah, your comment to James answer my question. They're distinguished by text inserted into drafts after C++03 but before that defect was raised in 2008. I think the current standard does what I said. Both my printed copy and my PDF of 2003(E) say, "An object or non-overloaded function is used if its name appears in a potentially-evaluated expression." with no exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

```
class Test {
    static const int GOOD = 0;
    static const int BAD = 1;
};
```

These are only *declarations*; they are not *definitions*.  You need to provide definitions of the static member variables, outside of the definition of the class, in one of your .cpp files:

```
const int Test::GOOD;
const int Test::BAD;
```

Alternatively, for integer constants, it is often more convenient to use an `enum`:

```
class Test {
    enum { 
        GOOD = 0,
        BAD = 1 
    };
};
```

Comment: Why does the lack of a definition bother the ternary operator but not the standard assignment operator?

Comment: It's not so simple as that. See my answer.

Comment: @Evan: Which assignment operator are you talking about? The one that assigns value to GOOD and BAD ?

Comment: @Evan:  I'm not 100% sure, however I'll take a stab at answering that:  when you use direct assignment, `GOOD` and `BAD` are only used directly as rvalues.  However, when you use the conditional operator, the conditional expression `num > 2 ? GOOD : BAD` is itself an lvalue expression, so the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion doesn't formally take place until after `GOOD` or `BAD` is selected, so actual objects (with definitions) are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine to me. And `ideone` agrees: see [this link](http://ideone.com/lmHaK). But that's with gcc-4.3.4. However, my gcc-4.4.0 doesn't accept it. So whatever the reason, it's not obvious.

**Edited to add:** The following variant compiles under gcc-4.4.0:

```
int localStatus = 42 ? GOOD : BAD;
```

Reminder: the following code doesn't compile:

```
int localStatus = (num == 42) ? GOOD : BAD;
```

So somebody has screwed up somewhere.

Comment: I am not sure if someone screwed up somewhere. I believe, that in the first case the only thing which happens, is, that the expression is optimized out. but the real problem is still there.