# Static constant class member declaration

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

in Foo.h:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    static const unsigned int FOOBAR = 10;
    static const unsigned int BARFOO = 20;

private:
    unsigned int m_FooBar;
    bool m_Bar;
    void Bar();
};
```

in Foo.cpp:

```
Foo::Foo()
    : m_FooBar(FOOBAR), // this works
      m_Bar(false)
{
}

void Foo::Bar()
{
    //m_FooBar = m_Bar ? FOOBAR : BARFOO; // linker fails *1
    m_FooBar = FOOBAR; // ok
}
```

I'm compiling with GCC 4.5.3. Is there any reason why the linker would fail when line *1 is uncommented?

```
Foo.o: In function 'Foo::Bar' (name unmangled):
Foo.cpp: undefined reference to `Foo::FOOBAR'
Foo.cpp: undefined reference to `Foo::BARFOO'
```

Tried with VC2005, 2008, 2010 and CB2010. They all compiled and linked fine. Why does GCC fail in this case?

Given the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446005/why-dont-static-member-variables-play-well-with-the-ternary-operator), why doesn't the other popular compilers fail like GCC? One way or another, it has to be a bug, either for GCC or the other popular compilers. Or is there a more reasonable explanation?

Comment: Hmm... It compiles fine in VS2010.

Comment: Compiles and links in CB2010 and VS2005 too

Comment: @Mysticial question is about gcc though. and I can confirm the linker error.

Comment: Confirmed in GCC 4.7.1. Error goes away when the static members are defined outside the class.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446005/why-dont-static-member-variables-play-well-with-the-ternary-operator

Comment: GCC 4.5.0, reproduced. Weird.

Comment: It's already been filed [as a bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53628).

Comment: @JesseGood Is it a bug? From the other SO question and its answers, it was determined that this isn't a bug!

Comment: @ZachSaw: Technically speaking, you are correct. It is not a bug per the ISO C++11 standard because the change to the standard was not voted into the working paper until February 2012 *after* the standard was ratified. However, since the commitee determined this to be a defect in the current standard, it was filed as bug to make sure any future versions of gcc exihibit the desired behavior (and because future standards will have these corrections).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formally, the header only declares the static constants, and they also have to be defined (at least in C++03). However, if you only use their values, you most often get away with this.

In C++11 this is more formally specified as requiring a definition when the static is "odr-used". The `*1` line is an example of this. The triadic operator tries to form a reference to the values, and the compiler (or linker actually) realizes that it cannot.

---

The C++11 standard says

> **9.4.2 Static data members**
>   §3...
>   The member shall still be defined
>   in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not
>   contain an *initializer*.

Comment: but in c++03 integer static constants are fine if declared and defined in the header, like in the questions

Comment: They are fine if you just use their values. The triadic operator produces a reference to one of the two values, which isn't possible when they are not defined. You get a similar effect if you try to pass one of the values by reference to a function.

Comment: So why aren't the other popular compilers doing that? If the triadic operator does that, shouldn't it fail on VC2010 too?

Comment: @Zach - Not all compilers follow the standard to the letter. :-) Some earlier VC versions even claimed that a definition wasn't allowed!

Comment: @BoPersson: Yup. VC6 wouldn't allow that at all!

Answer (score 0):

Try defining these members:

```
static const unsigned int FOOBAR = 10;
static const unsigned int BARFOO = 20;
```

Outside the class declaration.

```
Foo::FOOBAR = 10;
Foo::BARFOO = 20;
```